# Convert string month to numeric

Tags: date, stata

I have a variable `period` that contains a month as an abbreviated string (i.e. `"JAN"`, `"FEB"`, `"MAR"`, etc).  How do I convert `period` to a numeral (i.e. `1`, `2`, `3`, etc)?

My solution is:

```
gen fake_date_s = "2000"+period+"1"
gen fake_date = date(fake_date_s, "YMD")
gen month = month(fake_date)
```

Comment: Can you use an if statement or a switch statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's ugly:

```
clear

input ///
str3 period
JAN
FEB
DEC
end

list

gen monthnum = month(date("2000" + period + "1", "YMD"))

list
```

This also works:

```
gen monthnum = month(date(period, "M"))
```

as it sets the day and the year in the daily date to `01` and `1960`, by default.

I'm sure you can find an alternative that doesn't use date functions, but why not use them?

Comment: Consider also using -monthly()- in the same way, to get monthly dates directly. The route via daily dates can thus be shortened.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is:

```
local i=1
foreach m in `c(Mons)' {
    replace month = "`i'" if month == upper("`m'")
    local ++i
}

destring month, replace
```

Comment: `c(Mons)`: I learn something every time I come here. Very nifty.

Comment: @Brendan See `help creturn`.

Comment: @RobertoFerrer Yep, I was just browsing it. But it's a hard(er) section of the help files to find if you don't know such a function even exists in the first place!

Comment: @Brendan In Stata 13 manuals, **[U] 1** has a couple of mentions. Afterwards, it's all the way back to **[U] 13**.